# Programando para Android com múltiplas telas

Tags: java, android, xml, android-activity

Quando programo para `Android`, penso na portabilidade com os mais diversos dispositivos do mercado. Vendo o layout da minha `Activity` `principal`, notei que em dispositivos com tela pequena (fiz o teste com tela de 2 polegadas) as views são ENORMES e em dispositivos com tela grande (fiz o teste com tela de 10 polegadas) as views são MINIATURAS.

Como eu conserto tudo isso? Quando eu escrevia códigos `HTML`, utilizava no `CSS` a unidade % para a resolução do problema.

Comment: Como está a definir o tamanho das *views*? Poste um exemplo de um *layout*.

Comment: Da uma estudada no Fragments ;)
http://blog.caelum.com.br/layouts-mais-simples-com-android-fragments/

Comment: @Gabriel, alguma solução?

Answer (score 1):

Olá,

Você precisa tomar cuidado com tamanhos de tela desde o início do desenvolvimento, pois retroagir nesse sentido é ainda mais trabalhoso.

A maneira correta de lidar com isso é usando múltiplos resources para cada configuração de tela.

Observe o que diz a documentação a respeito disso:

> Using configuration qualifiers
>
> Android supports several configuration qualifiers that allow you to
>   control how the system selects your alternative resources based on the
>   characteristics of the current device screen. A configuration
>   qualifier is a string that you can append to a resource directory in
>   your Android project and specifies the configuration for which the
>   resources inside are designed.
>
> To use a configuration qualifier:
>
> Create a new directory in your project's res/ directory and name it
>   using the format: -  is the
>   standard resource name (such as drawable or layout).  is a
>   configuration qualifier from table 1, below, specifying the screen
>   configuration for which these resources are to be used (such as hdpi
>   or xlarge). You can use more than one  at a time—simply
>   separate each qualifier with a dash. Save the appropriate
>   configuration-specific resources in this new directory. The resource
>   files must be named exactly the same as the default resource files.
>   For example, xlarge is a configuration qualifier for extra-large
>   screens. When you append this string to a resource directory name
>   (such as layout-xlarge), it indicates to the system that these
>   resources are to be used on devices that have an extra-large screen.

Ou seja, você terá que ter dentro do seu projeto pastas dentro de resources específicas para cada configuração de tela seguindo o padrão `<resources_name>-<qualifier>`.

Algo semelhante a isso:

[image: Eu geralmente uso qualificadores de densidade nos meus projetos]

Para mais informações acesse o link abaixo. Ele contém toda informação necessária a respeito deste tema.

http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Espero ter ajudado.

Abraço.

Answer (score 1):

**Gabriel**

Temos algumas maneiras disponíveis para realizar essa manipulação de layouts em diferentes dispositivos.

**Drawable**

Disponibiliza os seguintes tamanhos

- ldpi (low) ~120dpi
- mdpi (medium) ~160dpi
- hdpi (high) ~240dpi
- xhdpi (extra-high) ~320dpi
- xxhdpi (extra-extra-high) ~480dpi
- xxxhdpi(extra-extra-extra-high) ~640dpi

Com isso cada arquivo dentro dessas pastas ira tratar um diferente tamanho de tela.

**Dimens.xml**

Esse xml que deve estar em `res/values/dimens.xml` nos possibilita realizar customizações tais como:

- Tamanho das views
- Tamanho de fontes
- Espaços entre margens (vide xml exemplo abaixo)
- Entre outros.

  ```
   <resources>

      <!-- Default screen margins, per the Android Design guidelines. -->
      <dimen name="activity_horizontal_margin">16dp</dimen>
      <dimen name="activity_vertical_margin">16dp</dimen>

   </resources>
  ```

**Nota:** Resumidamente SP para tipografia e DP para todo o resto.

**Fragments**

Temos desde a versão 3.0 `HoneyComb`  o uso de `Fragments` para a criação e layouts dinâmicos, pensando nos diversos tamanhos de tela que existem atualmente(Tablets e celulares com telas diferentes).

**Nota**: Você pode utilizar a biblioteca de suporte para versões inferiores, cuidado na hora do import deve ser:

```
android.support.v4.app.Fragment
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

A imagem acima demonstra os fragments em ação, por exemplo nos tablets a tela pode exibir por completo seu layout, quando você clicar em algum item da lista, sera carregado ao lado sem precisar mudar a iteração das telas, na figura do lado direito temos o uso dos fragments em dispositivos com telas menores onde temos **fragment A** que ao ser clicado direciona para o **fragment B, C** ou quantos forem necessários para montar sua tela.

Exemplo para inflar seu fragment retirado da [documentação](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html)

```
public static class ExampleFragment extends Fragment {
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.example_fragment, container, false);
    }
}
```

Para inflar os Fragments precisamos dar um Override no metodo `onCreateView` e retornar a view inflada, porém nada impede de usar também o método `OnCreate`só precisa ficar atento ao ciclo de vida do Fragment.

**Ciclo de vida dos Fragments**

**onAttach(activity)** - Esse método é chamado logo depois de o fragment ser associado com a activity

**onCreate(bundle)** - Esse método é chamado apenas uam vez e quando o fragment está sendo criado. Ele ira receber o Bundle que foi salvo durante o método onSaveInstanceState(state)

**onCreateView(inflater, viewgroup,bundle)** - Nesse método, o fragment precisa criar a view que será inserida no layout da activity>

**onActivityCreated(bundle)** - Esse método é chamado logo após o onCreate() da activity ter sido finalizado.

**onDestroyView()** - Esse método é chamado quando a view do fragment foi removida e não pertence mais ao fragment.

**onDestroy()** - Chamado para indicar que o fragment não está mais sendo utilizado.

**OnDetach()** - Oposto do método onAttach(activity).

Comment: A resposta citando fragments vai ao encontro da preocupação do AP, mas ele também dá a entender que o tamanho das views deveria ser proporcional à dimensão física da tela, e isso pode ser obtido independente do uso de fragments. Vide a outra resposta.

Comment: @Piovezan concordo com você, existe as duas possibilidades, qual abordagem você acha mais efetiva? trabalhar com todos os drawable ou ir direto para o uso dos fragments?

Comment: Primeiro acho que falta o autor da pergunta esclarecer o que quer exatamente. O que eu acho que falta complementar na resposta é que além dos drawable é possível definir dimensões diversas (tamanho das views, dos espaços entre elas, das fontes, etc.) conforme o tamanho da tela (em `res/values/dimens.xml`), dimensões essas que devem ser definidas em `dp` ou `sp` conforme o caso.

Comment: @Piovezan, dei uma complementada, se ele aparecer e explicar um pouco mais eu poderia deixar muito melhor a resposta.